# Full screen app on immersive mode

Tags: java, android

After the use of immersive mode, the navigation bar hides but app doesn't go  to full screen.

What am i doing wrong?

Below is my given `code` :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

---

[image]

Any help is valuable? Please help me with your answers.

Comment: can you post your activity_main.xml please

Comment: @Saeed Hashemi Hi can you tell me what's the yellow color thing you point in an arrow? I didn't get the idea from that image :| also what is your minimum sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use this: (FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make your activity full screen use the following code:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

use this inside onCreate().

Example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.example);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use this code snippet to acheive what you want.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    // Translucent status bar
    window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    // Translucent navigation bar
    window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
}
```

NOTE: the above code snippet doesn't need to be written above the `setContentView(R.layout.la);` or `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. This will display the other info (like time, battery, etc) on top but with your apps layout background.

Answer (score 2):

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that I am using in one of my production application which also takes care of android api versions [ImmersiveModeFragment.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ImmersiveMode/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/immersivemode/ImmersiveModeFragment.java).
It also takes care when you leave your app and resume it again. You can download the sample and try with all the features that an immersive app should have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I have been using on my Immersive Android App:

```
private void hideSystemUI()
{
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus)
        hideSystemUI();
}
```

Also call the `hideSystemUI()` right after the `setContentView()` method.
And on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add the attribute `android:immersive="true"` to your Activity tag.